# socket.io creates empty localStorage

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io v2.0.1 on my nodeJS server and today I spotted some odd behavior. I saw it indicates on google chrome that i have 1 "cookie" and when I checked it was some empty localStorage instance. Removing the `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` from my html page stops creating this instance. Is this normal behavior and how can I stop it? I am already using cookie:false option on my socket.io server

Comment: I believe that the `socket.io` client checks `localStorage` to see if it should be logging debug messages, so perhaps it'll initialize some sort of data structure. My guess is that it's normal behaviour that you probably can't disable.

Comment: is there any way to prevent the user from using the localStorage for debugging? I would really like not to display I am using any kind of local cookies/storage

Comment: No, you can't prevent your users from having control over their own browser.